# Where do files go if I lose a Remote Desktop session?

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

Where do files go if I lose a Terminal Services session and could reconnect until after my session had expired? Are they lost in the ether or would Windows save them somewhere?

Not sure if this matters, but I was working on a text file in Notepad and a .sql file in SQL Server Management Studio on a Windows 2003 server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log on again, look at Task Manager in the Users tab.

If your session is still there, right click it and click Connect. You'll be back where you started.

Otherwise, your files are gone.

Answer (score 2):

Things like office periodically save backups for you.  I suspect your notepad document is gone.  I wouldn't expect SQL Server Management Studio to save temp files either, but maybe.

You can look through your temporary files in your profile folder.

Comment: SSMS does save them in temp files, you'll get prompted to recover them when you run it again. It saved me a few times.